# Problems with syntax on MySQL trigger in PHP My Admin

Tags: mysql

I am having problems getting this trigger to work. Here is the code:

```
 BEGIN 

DECLARE newprice double;
DECLARE id int;
DECLARE rentdate DATE;

SET id := RESERVATION.RES_ID;
SET rentdate := "SELECT RES_RENT_DATE
FROM RESERVATION 
WHERE RES_ID = id";

SET newprice := (NEW.RES_RETURN_DATE - rentdate)*RESERVATION.RES_CAR_PPD;

UPDATE RESERVATION
SET RESERVATION.RES_TOTAL_PRICE = newprice WHERE  
RESERVATION.RES_ID = id;

END
```

Basically what I want to do is just update the total price when the return date of a car is changed. The trigger should execute on update of the Return Date. When updating it gives me the error: #1109 - Unknown table 'RESERVATION' in field list . I do not know what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several issues:

1. You can't arbitrarily refer to table columns like you did in `SET id := RESERVATION.RES_ID;`. You can refer to columns only either in a valid SQL statement (e.g. `SELECT`) or through `NEW`/`OLD`.
2. You can't issue DML statement (in your case `UPADTE`) on the same table on which you defined the trigger. This mutating behavior is prohibited in MySQL.
3. If I understand correctly and all values you need are in the same row, all you need is to use a `BEFORE` trigger. See example below.

Your trigger can be boiled down to this

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tg_bu_reservation
BEFORE UPDATE ON reservation
FOR EACH ROW
  SET NEW.res_total_price = (NEW.res_return_date - NEW.res_rent_date) * NEW.res_car_ppd;
```

**Note:** since it's a one statement trigger now there is no need in `BEGIN...END` block and changing a `DELIMITER`.

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f4e45/1)** demo